# How to join two sound interfaces?

Tags: sync, audio-interfaces, pro-tools-10

I'm using protools 10 hd in 2diffrent systems with two different audio interfaces. Is there way which I can have my two systems synced?can I join my interfaces in order to get the same time code?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the interface.  Normally something like this would be handled by a sync cable and a clock generator that establishes a common clock across devices.  This is only available on higher end interfaces though.  Using an external clock and sync cables is the only way I know of for reliable shared timecode on multiple distinct devices.  Your other option is just to sync after the fact as long as both have good internal clocks.

Comment: my interfaces are komplete audio 6 and M-audio audiophile ,can I sync them?how am I supposed to do this?

Comment: No you can not.  They do not support external sync.  You need something with [wordclock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_clock) sync support and that's only on higher end interfaces.  That said, if you can put both devices on the same computer, you can get pretty close with offsets if they have good timecode internally.  Recording to different computers is a problem though.